# Can you tell whether the linearity assumption holds by inspecting these graphs?

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression, data-visualization, residuals

The multiple regression model in R looks like this:
`> Model <- lm(log(Y) ~ log(x1) + x2 + x3 + x4 + log(x1)*x2, data=df)`, where `Y` and `x1` both are continuous variables and `x2`,`x3` and `x4` are categorical variables. `x2` contains 18 levels and `x3` contains 8 levels and `x4` contains 23 levels. Note that the response `Y` are measured in days and can only take on discrete values ranging from 1-365.

This model was chosen by stepwise regression in R and was evaluated by AIC, BIC and Adj-Rsquared.

When checking for the MLR assumptions by Gauss-Markov I am having trouble interpreting the Residual vs Fitted plot. I am trying to figure out whether the assumption about linearity hold true. Can someone please help with interpreting the following graphs?

Residual vs Fitted:
[image]

Scale-location:
[image]

Actual vs Predicted:
[image]

If the assumption does not hold, how would you go about fixing it?

Comment: Continuous is a treacherous word in statistics, yet there is often trust that treating data as approximately continuous is defensible. Here the stripes in the plots incline me to guess that you have discrete values that are, or are proportional to, 1, 2, 3, etc. Naturally, parallel but not equally spaced stripes are expected with a logarithmic transformation. Most crucially, the constraint that the response is positive gives a lower limit to the residual versus fitted plot, which must be remembered in interpretation. For this and other reasons some superimposed smoother is often a good idea.

Comment: The residuals have a bigger range than the fitted values!

Comment: An upper limit to the response is also discernible, it seems. More generally, I guess that more information about the data is needed to advise on a better model.

Comment: I guess you are right. Y is days ranging from 1-365 and x1 is cost measured in currency.

Comment: Depends then on what is being counted. I guess at days of year something is true so that 366 is possible in leap years but 367 is impossible. Is zero possible in principle? Some kind of logit model would seem to make sense if so.

Comment: Y are number of days that a individual was hospitalized, x1 is the total cost of the stay and the categorical variables are district, diagnosis code etc.Y cant take on the value 0, no.

Comment: I would use logit on say (days MINUS 0.5 ) / 366. (Treating extreme impossibilities symmetrically may not be vital in practice but it is a good principle.) Note that for small proportions $p$,  $\text{logit}\  p \approx \log p$, which I suspect is convenient as well as congenial for modeling such data.